# Aligning close icon in Bootstrap 4 tab

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to align a close icon for a `BootstrapVue` tab with Bootstrap 4.2 in the top right corner.

```
<b-tab v-for="order in tabs" :key="order.id">
    <template slot="title">
        <span class="float-left">{{ order.name }}</span>
        <b-button type="button" class="close float-right" aria-label="Close" @click="closeTab(order.id)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </b-button>
    </template>
    ...content....
</b-tab>
```

However, not only does it not align right as expected, the tab appears cut off when focussed:

[image]

What I want is for that `X` to appear in the top right corner of the tab.

How do I do that and make the tab look normal when active?

Comment: Don't put a `<button>` in a `.nav-item`! If you must, prepare yourself to override the entire CSS that comes with Bootstrap's buttons and their states (active, focus). Instead, you should use a simple anchor. Even the [pills variant](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs#pills-variant) (which look like buttons) use `<a>`s (look inside the page source). And the only class is `nav-link` (+ `active`, when active).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using BS4 then you can add this styling to make close button on top right

```
<button type="button" class="p-4 position-absolute top-0 right-0">
     <span>×</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case css position property is your friend

```
template {
position: relative;
} 
template button {
position: absolute;
right:0px;
}
```